# Why do we need halfword, byte, instead we could use only word for storing/loading (word)?

Tags: c, mips

In what particular cases we need to use lw/lh/lb?

```
strcpy:

addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $s0,0($sp)
add $s0, $zero,$zero    # $s0=0     i


addi $t1, $a1, $s0       #address of y
lbu $t2, 0($t1)         #$t2=y[]

addi $t3, $a0,$s0   #address of x
sb $t2,0($t3) 

beq $t3, $zero, L2
addi $s0, $s0, 1
j L1

L2: lw $s0, 0($sp)
      addi $sp, $sp, 4
jr $ra
```

this is the code that gives example of using lbu, but why not to use lw instead of lw or can we use here lh?Can you please explain the concepts behind using different opcodes?Thank you very much in advance=)

Comment: The destination string might not be padded to a word boundary. If you copy whole words, you'll overwrite whatever is after the destination string.

Comment: @Barmar, what did you by destination string? can you rephrase, please)

Comment: `strcpy()` copies from a source string to a destination string.

Comment: The C language requires memory to be addressable in bytes, so the hardware has instructions to support C.